# Showing Empty Screen in FlowListView in Xaml Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

**How to do FlowListView in XAML Xamarin.Forms?**

Here is my Code:

**XAML:**

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true" x:Name="grid_list" ItemsSource="{Binding list_grid}" HeightRequest="100" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="20" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
  </flv:FlowListView>
```

**CODE.cs**

```
 public partial class PlanCampaign_DetailPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<CarosualImages> list_grid { get; set; }
    public PlanCampaign_DetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;

        list_grid = new ObservableCollection<CarosualImages>()
        {

             new CarosualImages { Image="maharastra.jpg"},
             new CarosualImages {Image="delhi.jpg"},
             new CarosualImages {Image="delhi.jpg"},
             new CarosualImages {Image="delhi.jpg"},
             new CarosualImages {Image="delhi.jpg"},

        };

        grid_list.ItemsSource = list_grid;

    }
```

**ModelClass:**

```
public class CarosualImages
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Could anyone tell that where i did mistake here, this is showing Empty Screen.

Comment: I think you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Ok but, Can you tell me that how to implement ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class CarosualImages : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name = String.Empty;

    public CarosualImages()
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

     public string ImageName
     {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `Public` before

```
ObservableCollection<CarosualImages> list_grid { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?